# why symbol size reported by readelf is not same as objdump

Tags: elf

I have a Linux ELF file a.out, I use the following commands to extract disassembly result of _start

```
objdump -d ./a.out -F | awk -v RS= '/^[[:xdigit:]]+ <_start>/'
```

I get output as follows

```
00000000004008e0 <_start> (File Offset: 0x8e0):
  4008e0:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  4008e2:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  4008e5:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  4008e6:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  4008e9:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  4008ed:       50                      push   %rax
  4008ee:       54                      push   %rsp
  4008ef:       49 c7 c0 30 19 40 00    mov    $0x401930,%r8
  4008f6:       48 c7 c1 a0 18 40 00    mov    $0x4018a0,%rcx
  4008fd:       48 c7 c7 f0 05 40 00    mov    $0x4005f0,%rdi
  400904:       e8 d7 0a 00 00          callq  4013e0 <__libc_start_main> (File Offset: 0x13e0)
  400909:       f4                      hlt    
  40090a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

the above results said `_start` occupies  `0x40090a - 0x4008e0 + 6=48` bytes.
I also use

```
hexdump -C -s `echo ""|awk '{printf("%d", 0x8e0)}'` -n 48 ./a.out
```

to check the file content which is shown below

```
000008e0  31 ed 49 89 d1 5e 48 89  e2 48 83 e4 f0 50 54 49  |1.I..^H..H...PTI|
000008f0  c7 c0 30 19 40 00 48 c7  c1 a0 18 40 00 48 c7 c7  |..0.@.H....@.H..|
00000900  f0 05 40 00 e8 d7 0a 00  00 f4 66 0f 1f 44 00 00  |..@.......f..D..|
00000910
```

the above output is exactly the same with `objdump`

However, what I am confusing is that the `readelf -s` does not report _start with size `48` but `42`. See my command and output below.

```
readelf -s ./sub1.r.exe | awk '{if (NR==3) print $0; if ("1277:"==$1) print $0 }'
```

```
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
  1277: 00000000004008e0    42 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    6 _start
```

Why `readelf` does not report size `48` for symbol `_start`?

## Update

According to the comments, I wrote a bash program to check each symbol in `.text` section. (the script is not perfect but works for most cases)

```
while read line; do
    symbol=`echo $line | awk '{print $NF}'`
    size=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`


    objdump -d ./sub1.r.exe | awk -v RS= "/^[[:xdigit:]]+ <$symbol>/" > ./aaa.txt
    nlines=`cat aaa.txt | wc -l`
    [ $nlines -eq 0 ] && continue;


    app=$(tail aaa.txt -n 1 | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk \
        '{
            for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                if (match($i, "\\<[0-9a-f]{2}\\>")){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                   break;
                }
            }
            print i-1
        }')

    total=$(cat aaa.txt | awk -v n=$nlines -v a=$app \
    '{
        if (NR==2){
            ns = "0x" substr($1, 0, length($1)-1);
            start=strtonum(ns);
        }
        if (NR==n){
            ns = "0x" substr($1, 0, length($1)-1)
            stop =strtonum(ns);
        }
    } END {print stop-start + a}' )

    printf "%10d %-10d %4d %s\n" $total $size $((total%16)) $symbol

done < <(readelf -s ./a.out | awk '{if ($7==6 && $3>0) print $0}')
```

Although many symbols' sizes obey the alignment constraints. the output of the above script does not prove that each symbol will obey 16-byte alignment constraints. Some of them do not obey that constraint.
You can use `gcc -static` to compile any source file to get an ELF file to check it with the script above.

## Update 2

I extract function `backtrace_and_maps`'s disassembled output from `objdump -d` as showing below.

```
0000000000400390 <backtrace_and_maps> (File Offset: 0x390):
  400390:   ff cf                   dec    %edi
  400392:   0f 8e 3a 01 00 00       jle    4004d2 <backtrace_and_maps+0x142> (File Offset: 0x4d2)
  400398:   40 84 f6                test   %sil,%sil
  40039b:   0f 84 31 01 00 00       je     4004d2 <backtrace_and_maps+0x142> (File Offset: 0x4d2)
  4003a1:   55                      push   %rbp
  4003a2:   53                      push   %rbx
  4003a3:   be 40 00 00 00          mov    $0x40,%esi
  4003a8:   89 d5                   mov    %edx,%ebp
  4003aa:   48 81 ec 08 06 00 00    sub    $0x608,%rsp
  4003b1:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  4003b4:   e8 97 2c 04 00          callq  443050 <__backtrace> (File Offset: 0x43050)
  4003b9:   83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax
  4003bc:   41 89 c0                mov    %eax,%r8d
  4003bf:   0f 8e 04 01 00 00       jle    4004c9 <backtrace_and_maps+0x139> (File Offset: 0x4c9)
  4003c5:   48 63 dd                movslq %ebp,%rbx
  4003c8:   ba 1d 00 00 00          mov    $0x1d,%edx
  4003cd:   be 08 26 4a 00          mov    $0x4a2608,%esi
  4003d2:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  4003d5:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4003da:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4003dc:   48 3d 00 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
  4003e2:   76 0c                   jbe    4003f0 <backtrace_and_maps+0x60> (File Offset: 0x3f0)
  4003e4:   48 c7 c2 d0 ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffd0,%rdx
  4003eb:   f7 d8                   neg    %eax
  4003ed:   64 89 02                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rdx)
  4003f0:   41 8d 70 ff             lea    -0x1(%r8),%esi
  4003f4:   48 8d 7c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
  4003f9:   89 ea                   mov    %ebp,%edx
  4003fb:   e8 b0 2c 04 00          callq  4430b0 <__backtrace_symbols_fd> (File Offset: 0x430b0)
  400400:   ba 1d 00 00 00          mov    $0x1d,%edx
  400405:   be 26 26 4a 00          mov    $0x4a2626,%esi
  40040a:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  40040d:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  400412:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400414:   48 3d 00 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
  40041a:   76 0c                   jbe    400428 <backtrace_and_maps+0x98> (File Offset: 0x428)
  40041c:   48 c7 c2 d0 ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffd0,%rdx
  400423:   f7 d8                   neg    %eax
  400425:   64 89 02                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rdx)
  400428:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  40042a:   bf 44 26 4a 00          mov    $0x4a2644,%edi
  40042f:   b8 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%eax
  400434:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400436:   48 3d 00 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
  40043c:   76 10                   jbe    40044e <backtrace_and_maps+0xbe> (File Offset: 0x44e)
  40043e:   48 c7 c2 d0 ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffd0,%rdx
  400445:   f7 d8                   neg    %eax
  400447:   64 89 02                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rdx)
  40044a:   48 83 c8 ff             or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
  40044e:   4c 63 c0                movslq %eax,%r8
  400451:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400453:   41 ba 01 00 00 00       mov    $0x1,%r10d
  400459:   ba 00 04 00 00          mov    $0x400,%edx
  40045e:   48 8d b4 24 00 02 00    lea    0x200(%rsp),%rsi
  400465:   00 
  400466:   4c 89 c7                mov    %r8,%rdi
  400469:   89 e8                   mov    %ebp,%eax
  40046b:   0f 05                   syscall 
  40046d:   48 3d 00 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
  400473:   49 89 c1                mov    %rax,%r9
  400476:   76 1a                   jbe    400492 <backtrace_and_maps+0x102> (File Offset: 0x492)
  400478:   48 c7 c0 d0 ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffd0,%rax
  40047f:   41 f7 d9                neg    %r9d
  400482:   64 44 89 08             mov    %r9d,%fs:(%rax)
  400486:   4c 89 c7                mov    %r8,%rdi
  400489:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
  40048e:   0f 05                   syscall 
  400490:   eb 37                   jmp    4004c9 <backtrace_and_maps+0x139> (File Offset: 0x4c9)
  400492:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  400495:   7e ef                   jle    400486 <backtrace_and_maps+0xf6> (File Offset: 0x486)
  400497:   4c 89 ca                mov    %r9,%rdx
  40049a:   48 8d b4 24 00 02 00    lea    0x200(%rsp),%rsi
  4004a1:   00 
  4004a2:   48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
  4004a5:   44 89 d0                mov    %r10d,%eax
  4004a8:   0f 05                   syscall 
  4004aa:   48 3d 00 f0 ff ff       cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax
  4004b0:   76 10                   jbe    4004c2 <backtrace_and_maps+0x132> (File Offset: 0x4c2)
  4004b2:   48 c7 c2 d0 ff ff ff    mov    $0xffffffffffffffd0,%rdx
  4004b9:   f7 d8                   neg    %eax
  4004bb:   64 89 02                mov    %eax,%fs:(%rdx)
  4004be:   48 83 c8 ff             or     $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
  4004c2:   49 39 c1                cmp    %rax,%r9
  4004c5:   74 92                   je     400459 <backtrace_and_maps+0xc9> (File Offset: 0x459)
  4004c7:   eb bd                   jmp    400486 <backtrace_and_maps+0xf6> (File Offset: 0x486)
  4004c9:   48 81 c4 08 06 00 00    add    $0x608,%rsp
  4004d0:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  4004d1:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004d2:   c3                      retq   

00000000004004d3 <detach_arena.part.0> (File Offset: 0x4d3):
  4004d3:   50                      push   %rax
  4004d4:   b9 68 38 4a 00          mov    $0x4a3868,%ecx
  4004d9:   ba 75 02 00 00          mov    $0x275,%edx
  4004de:   be e8 29 4a 00          mov    $0x4a29e8,%esi
  4004e3:   bf c0 2d 4a 00          mov    $0x4a2dc0,%edi
  4004e8:   e8 93 71 01 00          callq  417680 <__malloc_assert> (File Offset: 0x17680)
```

I also extract the binary content with offset 0x390 to the elf file and with length `0x4004d2 - 0x400390 + 1 + 5 = 328` as showing below.

```
00000390  ff cf 0f 8e 3a 01 00 00  40 84 f6 0f 84 31 01 00  |....:...@....1..|
000003a0  00 55 53 be 40 00 00 00  89 d5 48 81 ec 08 06 00  |.US.@.....H.....|
000003b0  00 48 89 e7 e8 97 2c 04  00 83 f8 02 41 89 c0 0f  |.H....,.....A...|
000003c0  8e 04 01 00 00 48 63 dd  ba 1d 00 00 00 be 08 26  |.....Hc........&|
000003d0  4a 00 48 89 df b8 01 00  00 00 0f 05 48 3d 00 f0  |J.H.........H=..|
000003e0  ff ff 76 0c 48 c7 c2 d0  ff ff ff f7 d8 64 89 02  |..v.H........d..|
000003f0  41 8d 70 ff 48 8d 7c 24  08 89 ea e8 b0 2c 04 00  |A.p.H.|$.....,..|
00000400  ba 1d 00 00 00 be 26 26  4a 00 48 89 df b8 01 00  |......&&J.H.....|
00000410  00 00 0f 05 48 3d 00 f0  ff ff 76 0c 48 c7 c2 d0  |....H=....v.H...|
00000420  ff ff ff f7 d8 64 89 02  31 f6 bf 44 26 4a 00 b8  |.....d..1..D&J..|
00000430  02 00 00 00 0f 05 48 3d  00 f0 ff ff 76 10 48 c7  |......H=....v.H.|
00000440  c2 d0 ff ff ff f7 d8 64  89 02 48 83 c8 ff 4c 63  |.......d..H...Lc|
00000450  c0 31 ed 41 ba 01 00 00  00 ba 00 04 00 00 48 8d  |.1.A..........H.|
00000460  b4 24 00 02 00 00 4c 89  c7 89 e8 0f 05 48 3d 00  |.$....L......H=.|
00000470  f0 ff ff 49 89 c1 76 1a  48 c7 c0 d0 ff ff ff 41  |...I..v.H......A|
00000480  f7 d9 64 44 89 08 4c 89  c7 b8 03 00 00 00 0f 05  |..dD..L.........|
00000490  eb 37 48 85 c0 7e ef 4c  89 ca 48 8d b4 24 00 02  |.7H..~.L..H..$..|
000004a0  00 00 48 89 df 44 89 d0  0f 05 48 3d 00 f0 ff ff  |..H..D....H=....|
000004b0  76 10 48 c7 c2 d0 ff ff  ff f7 d8 64 89 02 48 83  |v.H........d..H.|
000004c0  c8 ff 49 39 c1 74 92 eb  bd 48 81 c4 08 06 00 00  |..I9.t...H......|
000004d0  5b 5d c3 50 b9 68 38 4a                           |[].P.h8J|
000004d8
```

I also `grep` the output of `readelf -s` as showing below

```
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
   103: 0000000000400390   323 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 backtrace_and_maps
```

As you can see, function `backtrace_and_maps` do occupy 323 bytes which is not aligned by 16-bit or 8-bit.

Comment: I'm quite certain that the `hlt` instruction is the last of the `_start` function, and that the `nop` instruction is some uninitialized data to pad up the code to an even size (for 8- or 16-byte alignment).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. So the CPU will execute one additional useless instruction? Also, I found that `_start` is in `.text` section and this section's `sh_addralign` is `16`. Is this `16` used as an alignment constraint for each symbol in `.text` section? But `man elf` does not mention that the alignment constraint applies to each symbol.

Comment: The `hlt` instruction halts execution. But it's very likely that the called `_libc_start_main` function will call `exit` or `_exit` so the program will never reach it anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have checked for all symbols in `.text` section (see my update), it seems that not every symbol obeys the alignment constraints.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what symbols do and what does not follow that alignment. And what *kind* of symbol each is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have uploaded an example of this kind of function. now I think maybe only some of the symbols obey the alignment constraints. but I cannot find related formal reports or other material to support my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

> Why readelf does not report size 48 for symbol _start

Symbol size (at least for `.text` symbols) is completely optional. While compilers usually set it, assembly code often does not.

When `objdump` disassembles a function, it pays no attention to the symbol size. It simply assumes that anything between one label and the next one constitutes a function.

Example:

```
// foo.s
foo:
  nop; nop; nop
bar:
  nop; nop;
  .size foo, .-foo
  .size bar, .-bar
  nop; nop
baz:
  nop
```

Compile with `gcc -c foo.s`. Symbol sizes:

```
 readelf -Ws foo.o

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 6 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 0000000000000000     5 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 foo
     5: 0000000000000003     2 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 bar
     6: 0000000000000007     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 baz
```

Disassembly from `objdump`:

```
objdump -d foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   90                      nop
   1:   90                      nop
   2:   90                      nop

0000000000000003 <bar>:
   3:   90                      nop
   4:   90                      nop
   5:   90                      nop
   6:   90                      nop

0000000000000007 <baz>:
   7:   90                      nop
```

Note that ELF symbol size for `foo` is larger than `objdump` output for it (because we've included part of `bar` in it), and ELF symbol size for `bar` is smaller than `objdump` output. `baz` has no size at all (we didn't set it).

Comment: If the compiler sets the symbol size, why is the size incorrect?

Comment: @aban It's _not_ incorrect. You are comparing it with a value which you shouldn't compare it with (which includes padding).